# Strange character instead of arrow in Linux Chrome New tab page

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I'm using Google Chrome dev channel on Linux. Recent update to 29.0.1521.3 breaks the little arrow on page switcher (at the left or right of the new tab page), instead there's some weird strange characters ("â€¹" and "â€º").

What's more, if I remove ~/.config/google-chrome and ~/.cache/google-chrome, that page backs to normal. But when I sign into my Google account, those strange characters appear again. Tried adjusting font settings in browser, but no effect.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just found this bug:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244049

Seems it has been fixed.

Comment: Remember to accept this answer if it solved your problem (even better, include the basic info from the link you posted).